# How to subtract value from one array to another and create a new Array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 arrays **A** and **B** with the same length, and I would like to subtract '**balance**' and '**total**' from **A** to **B** and create a 
   new array '**C**' with subtracted value   ....................................................................................

```
A = [
{
    "ID": 1,
    "balance": 100,
    "total": 1000,
    "date": "10/24/2019",
},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "balance": 200,
    "total": 2000,
    "date": "10/24/2019",
}
]

 B =[
{
    "ID": 1,
    "balance": 80,
    "total": 800,
    "date": "10/23/2019",
},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "balance": 90,
    "total": 900,
    "date": "10/23/2019",
}
]
```

**New Array (A - B = C)**

```
C = [
{
    "ID": 1,
    "balance": 20,
    "total": 200,
},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "balance": 110,
    "total": 1100,
}
]
```

Comment: please add your try. are the data with the same `ID` on same index.

Comment: yes, same ID and index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain of the length & position of the arrays you could iterate over the length of one of them:

```
const A = [];
const B = [];

const C = A.map((item, index) => ({
        ID: item.ID,
        balance: item.balance - B[index].total,
        total: item.total - B[index].total
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The array contains objects

```
var C=[];
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  result={};
  result.ID=A[i].ID;
  result.balance=A[i].balance-B[i].balance;
  result.total=A[i].total-B[i].total;//if it makes sense
  C.push(result);
}
console.log(C);
```